# como ejecutar varios script desde un script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Como puedo lanzar desde un script principal otros scripts. Porfa ayuda.

Me evitaria crear un script por cada script que desee ejecutar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede hacer de la siquiente manera:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/bin/scripts/

sh script1.sh & sh script2.sh & sh script3.sh
```

Comment: Si tienen permiso de ejecución no necesitan sh delante del script, ya que el script tendría el propio intérprete y el sistema lo llamaría automaticamente

Comment: esto es incorrecto. Con un solo `&`, se ejecutará en background. El "and" se consigue con `&&`

Comment: Si necesitas que se ejecuten varios scripts en background desde un script principal la solucion es con &. He probado el &&,punto y coma y source y lo unico que hace es ejecutar el primer script y el segundo no se llega a ejecutar.

Comment: `sh s1.sh && sh s2.sh && ...` sí funciona. Haz la prueba poniendo `echo 1` en cada uno de ellos.